# Maple 2023 plot() function is working very strange with composite functions. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: math, numerical-methods, maple

I am trying to make a period function which is oscilating between 1 and 0. I made a function which is oscilating how i need on an interval <0,7), when i tried to make it periodical i wrote a modified modulo function (which accounts for modulo not being continuous) but when i make a composite function it is not plotting correctly.

Has anybody seen anything similar?

[image: Maple 2023 plot(modulo(t)) vs plot(modulo)]

When I use plot(function) the function is displayed correctly but i cannot change the graph scale.
(if i change it it breaks the graph)
when I use plot(function(t)) it is not working correctly and displayes only some basic linear function.
when I use plot with some parameters it also doesn't work.

Maple 2023 code:

```
sigmoid := t -> 1/(1 + exp(-t));
weekend_function := t -> piecewise(0 <= t and t < 2.5, 0, 2.5 <= t and t < 3.5, sigmoid(12*t - 36), 3.5 <= t and t < 4.5, 1 - sigmoid(12*t - 48), 4.5 <= t, 0);
modulo := t -> (floor(t) mod 7) + t - floor(t);
fun := t -> weekend_function(modulo(t));
plot(modulo);
plot(fun);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a procedure in Maple, and pass it arguments, those arguments are *evaluated* before the procedure starts to act on them. The evaluation of passed arguments is done "up front".

That's Maple's normal evaluation model of handling procedural arguments.

You constructed this procedure:

```
modulo := t -> (floor(t) mod 7) + t - floor(t):
```

Now, let's evaluate the following,

```
modulo(t);

      t
```

Yes, the result is just `t`. That happens because of the following result, when `t` is just an unassigned name:

```
floor(t) mod 7;

    floor(t)
```

So, if you were to call,

```
plot( modulo(t) );
```

then the `plot` command would actually receive simply `t`, ie. the result of evaluating `modulo(t)`.

In contrast, when you called,

```
plot( modulo )
```

you were invoking the so-called operator form calling sequence of the `plot` command, and in that scenario `modulo` is only ever itself called with actual numeric arguments (ie. not just the name, `t`).

You can fix your approach in several ways.

Method 1) Use single right-ticks (a.k.a. "uneval quotes"), to delay evaluation of the first thing passed to `plot`.

These work,

```
plot('modulo'(t));
plot('fun'(t));
```

Method 2) Define your `modulo` procedure differently, so that it returns its own call (*unevaluated*), if you call it with just a name like `t` or something non-numeric.

```
modulo2 := proc(t)
  if not type(t,numeric) then
    return 'procname'(args);
  else
    (floor(t) mod 7) + t - floor(t);
  end if;
end proc:
```

Now, look, this doesn't just return `t`

```
modulo2(t);

    modulo2(t)
```

And so now these work,

```
plot(modulo2(t));

fun2 := t -> weekend_function(modulo2(t)):

plot(fun2(t))
```